# How to easily debug SOCKETs implementation on Android

Tags: android, sockets, debugging, socket.io

I implemented socket on my Android application using `Socket.IO` library. Now I want to really see what data is being sent through the socket - how can I test that?
Android native network profiler does not work in this scenerio - it says data unavailable.
I tried to use `Stetho`, but even that did not help me to see the data passing through my socket. Any ideas on which software to use for this case and maybe step by step guide would be perfect. Thanks.